# How to hide my Google Play downloads from my friends?

Tags: google-play-store, privacy

I am new to android and just by going into Google Play I can see every app my friends downloaded. I am really feeling uncomfortable about this since I don't like to feel exposed.

Does anyone knows how to block this "feature"?

Comment: Is that really the case? I thought you'd only see the apps your friends actually rated, not downloaded. In any case, I agree with you, I don't like that feature either.

Comment: Where do you see this list(?) of apps your friends have downloaded?

Comment: When I search an app I can see some friends there in the app page. At first I thought it only showed the apps my friends rated but then I found an app with just an indication of a friend who downloaded it

Comment: Odd. Mine seems to only show ones I've +1'd or rated.... The +1's might be the setting at https://plus.google.com/u/0/apps/google (no idea).

Comment: Yep, I mistaken it, indeed just the ones people +1'd....my bad!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that there is any trick available which you can use to hide the apps downloaded from your friends until or unless you unfriend your friends over your G+ account.

But I have got another trick for you which is going to work for you like whenever you download app, try getting the .apk file downloaded from third party sites say I want to download whatsapp and don't want my friends to see. I will download whatsapp.apk file directly from the Whatsapp website and then I can install the apk file independently and my friends will never know that I have downloaded whatsapp, just make sure you don't get the apps from PlayStore and it will not be shown!

Comment: But you need to be aware that apps from third party websites may not be as safe as apps from the app store

Comment: Hmmmm so this isn't related to the system itself it is just related to the play store...any way to test it?

Comment: @mFeinstein You can test by downloading free apps from Amazon's app store

Comment: And how can I see if my friends see that I have the app or not?

Comment: @mfeinstein by asking them? That is the only way you will will know for sure even with the Google app store

Comment: Well, @joeW yes you are correct, we need to be aware of the apps from third party site but I guess that can be done directly from PlayStore there are some sites like [Apps Evozi](http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/) here what you need to do is put the Google Play Link of the app you need to get apk of, and after pasting the link tap over the generate link ! Done .apk file of any app directly from Google Play.

Comment: I deleted everyone from my google plus account and I still can see my friends who liked stuff and commented. Actually I can see people that I didn't even had at google plus, so I guess it's reading my contacts.

Comment: On the other hand I think I misunderstood the system and I can only see the ones who likes the apps. I saw their names with the +1 and thought it was like a download sign. Sorry for being dumb haha I really don't use google plus for anything

Comment: @mFeinstein that might be because of your contacts stored we just couldn't guess where Google is reading things from !

Comment: I also think it's from my contacts...still, kinda scary hahaha

Comment: AFAIK apps that are installed from apk files can only be  updated manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide your game activity. Go to your profile and click on edit. There will be checkboxes for "People to see your gamer ID through your Google+ name" and and another to "Hide your gaming activity". Uncheck them, and you're good to go!